# WPF RichTextBox Document Bind using Binding property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

If is it Possible RichTextBox Document Property Support Binding as FlowDocument.

Comment: [Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not a `DependencyProperty` so it can't be databound directly. If I solved your word-puzzle correctly.

Comment: What have you tried?  Put more effort into the question.  All of your questions are hard to understand.  I get that English may be a second language but you don't even have good formatting.  And not a single accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. A flow document is meant to be used as a report, not an editor of a document.